# ImageSlider with image viewer for iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, imageview

I am creating image slider in my app. It looks like this. There are small images that I can scroll horizontally and when I touch each of them - big image viewer is opened.

[image: slider with images]
[image: image viewer]

For slider I created UICollectionView and each cell is image. If I click on cell the separate ViewController (that works as image viewer) is loaded. In this view there is UIImageView for big image.

And this my list of questions:
1) What is the best way to make user be able to changing images in image viewer  by swiping
2) Where I should care about memory usage most of all. Because even with few small images it is not looking very smooth in simulator.
3) Is this the right way for creating image slide viewer or I am missing something? Maybe there is some framework that deals with it with cache async loading and other cool features?

Comment: What is your idea if go with UIPageViewController, I mean You can take two image view on contentviewcontroller one for small images and another for big images.For first time you can show small image gallery & hide big images,  when user click on any image you can hide small image gallery I show big image with animation you want.

Comment: To swipe between the images, create an array of Images, and whenever the user swipes, use: **ImageView.image = myImages[i+1]** or **[i-1]**, where **i** will serve as a counter through the images. And when you select the image and prepare for segue, pass the i value to the detailed image view controller. This is really handy, since you can use the **i** value to create that "i / 15"

Answer (score 1):

I do not know where your image came from. Is it from server or copied to bundle in the app?

For small images u should use thumbnails (do not load big images there, instead preprocess the images and create thumbnail like 500x500 beforehand or smaller and show that). If you load from server, look up "lazy loading images", using GCD to handle asynchronous process.

Using CollectionView for this purpose is fine. Alternatively you could customize UIPickerView to have that "snapping" effect at the chosen image instead of free scrolling. The other other alternative is, custom control which you may find in github.

**Edit**: if your scrolling suffers for CollectionView, chances are you might be using layer.masksToBound=YES. This will make performance bad. Do not use this.